# Selecting one value from XML with XSL for-each

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am trying to select the language from an XML stylesheet. I have combo boxes with multiple languages. I want to be able to select a language and then transform various innerHTML IDs. So far, I have gotten it to work but it goes through every element and transforms it into the one that I want, then outputs all the elements. Basically, I changed a title but instead of it being 'title' it comes out as 'title title title title' for as many child nodes there are.

Here is my XSL

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:param name="languageToBeSelected" />
<xsl:template match="/newdataset/language">
        <xsl:for-each select="/newdataset/language">
            <xsl:if test="englishtype = $languageToBeSelected"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="premierlimited" />    
            </xsl:if>   
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And a snippet of my XML

```
<newdataset>
    <language>
        <englishtype>Ukrainian</englishtype>
        <premierlimited>Прем'єр обмеженою</premierlimited>

        </language>

        <language>
        <englishtype>Arabic</englishtype>
        <premierlimited>رئيس مجلس الدولة المحدودة</premierlimited>

    </language>
</newdataset>
```

If I was to run the above code and choose the Arabic one it would produce

```
رئيس مجلس الدولة المحدودة رئيس مجلس الدولة المحدودة
```

How can I get it to only output the result once?

Answer (score 3):

In your XML snippet you have two **language** elements, this means the template `<xsl:template match="/newdataset/language">` gets matched twice, one for each element. However, within this template you are using an **xsl:for-each** to iterate over all **language** elements again until you find a match. Because the template is being called twice, you end up with two matches.

The answer is simply to remove the **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:param name="languageToBeSelected" />
<xsl:template match="/newdataset/language">
        <xsl:if test="englishtype = $languageToBeSelected"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="premierlimited" />    
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: OMG! I want to hug and kiss you. I feel so dumb.